# Problemas com GlassFish PermGen Space

Tags: java, java-ee, aplicação-web, servidor, glassfish

Possuo um projeto que executa um sistema web de controle, ele possui um web service rest para consultas e coleta de dados de dispositivos móveis.
Ele executa perfeitamente, mas o projeto está ainda em desenvolvimento. Já aconteceu três vezes, de o Glassfish travar e exibir a mensagem do erro PermGen Space. Mando ele reiniciar, mas ele fica tentando implantar e nada. Consegui resolver isso a primeira vez removendo o server, adicionando-o novamente, criando novo domain e criando um novo projeto com essa nova instancia do server. Mas se eu tiver que fazer isso todo dia, vai faltar HD e não termino o projeto.

Estou usando NetBeans 7.3.1 | JDK 1.7 | Glassfish 4.0

Preciso resolver urgente isso. Se alguem puder ajudar, ficarei agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Problema de memória Heap.

1. No arquivo "domain.xml" presente no diretório

   /glassfish/domain/domain1/config

encontre:

```
<jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=
```

Atribua um valor 256m ou 512m

2. Encerre o processo do Glassfish pelo terminal, exemplo o meu roda naporta 8080:

   sudo netstat -npl | grep 8080

Isto deverá resultar alguma coisa tipo

```
tcp6 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN **3312**/java
```

Então mate o processo:

```
kill -9 **3312** (note que 3312 é o numero do processo resultante acima).
```

Tente subir novamente o Glassfish.

No Windows não sei os comandos para encerrar, mas acredito que se reiniciar a máquina, consiga resolver, depois de acertar o arquivo xml no passo 1.